# How can I connect to a DataBase using EJB2.0

Tags: java, ejb

How can I connect to a DataBase using EJB2.0.Can I use JDBC for that.Otherwise what are the alternate options available.

Comment: @maksimov Hi Because of your anti-voting I cant ask questions in the forum.I was only trying to explore the various alternatives for DB operations in a DB enbvironment. I have been using EJB for the last 3 years.Please revert the same.

Comment: The down-vote button has this caption on it: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)". Please improve your question and I will be happy to click the down-vote button again to undo my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to connect to your database either through an ORM such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). You could also use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html) or [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Comment: Sorry.I was only meaning that to get various different ways available.

Comment: Hi maksimov, Because of your anti-voting I cant ask questions in the forum.I was only trying to explore the various alternatives for DB operations in a DB enbvironment. Please revert the same.

Comment: @user1281029: If you want to pass a message to `maksimov`, then, I would recommend you write a comment underneath his and start it with @maksimov This should notify him/her of a message.